# Popping a node of a shortest path from the queue using dijkstra

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes, openstreetmap, dijkstra

I have a shortest path calculated using a properly implemented dijkstra algorithm. It goes from A to F via B, C, D and E. So the whole shortest path is [A, B, C, D, E, F].

Now I want to go from G to F. When popping C from the queue I realize that it is part of a shortest path to F. Does that mean that I also know that the shortest path from G to F is [G, H, C, D, E, F]?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But it *does* mean that the shortest path from **C** to **F** is [C, D, E, F].

If there were a shorter path, `P` then we contruct a new path from A to F [A,B,[P]] which is inherently shorter than our original path. This is a contradiction as we assumed [A,B,C,D,E,F] was the shortest path from A to F.

This can be generalized to prove that the sub-path of a shortest path is also a shortest path. In your case this means that if a shortest path from G to F contains C then that shortest path contains [C, D, E, F] as a subpath. Since you do not know if C is in your shortest path this theorem will only help you reduce the number of calculations if you store the weight of the shortest path from C to F.

Comment: That is probably why people usually also draw costs when they draw graphs. Obviously I -> F could e.g. be 6, C -> F also 6 and H -> 1. My bad. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think not, since you have to take in account the distance from H to C.
What if the the distance [H, C] is huge, let's say greater than the distance [H, I, F]?

Comment: But if [H, I, F] would be shorter than [H, C] I would arrive at F before popping C from the queue?!

Comment: But consider [H,I] has a larger weight than [H,C] but the rest of the path, [I to F] has a much smaller weight than [C, D,E,F]

Comment: I agree. Mine was a bad example.But I think the one in Michael's comment is correct and clarifying.